# How to save picture in the database

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to save my data to database
Where does the statement to save a picture in the database fit?

```
        Dim drNewRowMCQsAns As DataRow
        drNewRowMCQsAns = DsResultSaveNow.tblResult.NewRow

        drNewRowMCQsAns.Item("PaperID") = vrPaperIDInitialized
        drNewRowMCQsAns.Item("StudentID") = vrStudentID
        drNewRowMCQsAns.Item("StudentName") = vrStudentName

        DsResultSaveNow.tblResult.Rows.Add(drNewRowMCQsAns)
        taResultSaveNow.Update(DsResultSaveNow.tblResult)
```

I have image field in the database but how to save an image?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the image data is simply a byte array

```
Dim imageData as Byte()
```

Load your image into the byte array from where ever you are getting it from and set it just like the other properties

```
drNewRowMCQsAns.Item("ImageData") = imageData
```

Loading image into array:

From file:

```
        imageData = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\filename.jpg")
```

From bitmap:

```
        Dim bitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap("c:\filename.jpg")
    Dim tempMemStream As New IO.MemoryStream
    bitmap.Save(tempMemStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    imageData = tempMemStream.ToArray()
```

Comment: and can we use this image like we normally load images to the image box (fromfile method)