# i want save a picture into daatabase

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim a As New OpenFileDialog
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\USER\DOWNLOADS\SDP(BACKUP1)\SDP(BACKUP)\SDP.MDF;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Announcement ([name],[picture]) VALUES('" & nameTB.Text & "',@a2)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@a2", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PictureBox2.BackgroundImage) 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Event Announcement submitted!")

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Operation Failed! Please Check Again!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

this is what i had try....i can choose a image but i cant save it(which mean complete save a picture into database) all that thing in google teach me save picture in sql server or access.. i had try it...but the very last thing i dunt understand is how can i parameter @a2 with picturebox? 
it give error for IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PictureBox2.BackgroundImage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save picture in the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861038/how-to-save-picture-in-the-database) plus "About 128,000" others according to Google

Comment: Literally typed into google "how to save a picture in a database vb.net" and got *just a few* tutorials on this... just a few mind! :P

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes wants a file.  You gave it an image.  You need a memory stream, not a file stream.

Comment: @LarsTech may show me some logic? which part i should change, so my "@a2" can parameter to picturebox?

Comment: that is **precisely** what the answer on the linked question does.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, File.ReadAllBytes wants a file, not an image.  So you need to use a MemoryStream instead:

```vb
Using ms As New MemoryStream
  PictureBox2.BackgroundImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", ms.ToArray)
End Using
```